# Rails: redirect issues. Encounter weird 302 status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, http-status-code-302

While following rails routes to build the whole CRUD system, I encountered an issue where an 302 status code would occur after performing create, update and delete actions.
The page would be redirected to "show" instead of "index" as I coded.

**controller.rb**

```rb
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @candidates = Candidate.all
  end

  def new
    @candidate = Candidate.new
  end

  def create
    @candidate = Candidate.new(filtered)
    if @candidate.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully Added!"
      redirect_to 'candidates_path'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @candidate = Candidate.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @candidate = Candidate.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    
    p @candidate = Candidate.find_by(id: params[:id])

    if @candidate.update(filtered)
      flash[:notice] = "Candidate Updated :)"
      redirect_to 'candidates_path'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    
    p @candidate = Candidate.find_by(id: params[:id])
    
    @candidate.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully Deleted!"
    redirect_to 'candidates_path'
  end


  private
  def filtered
    params.require(:candidate).permit(:name, :party, :age, :politics)
  end
end
```

**Views:index**

```html
<h1> Candidate Index </h1>
<div><%= link_to 'Add new candidate', new_candidate_path %></div>
<div><%= flash[:notice] %> </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Party</td>
    <td>Politics</td>
  </tr>
  <% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to candidate.name, candidate_path(candidate.id) %></td>
    <td><%= candidate.age %></td>
    <td><%= candidate.party %></td>
    <td><%= candidate.politics %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_candidate_path(candidate.id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'delete', candidate_path(candidate.id), method: 'delete', data: {confirm: "Please confirm delete"} %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**Views: show**

```html
<h1> Candidate Info </h1>
<% if @candidate %>
<tr>
  <td><%= @candidate.name %></td>
  <td><%= @candidate.age %></td>
  <td><%= @candidate.party %></td>
  <td><%= @candidate.politics %></td>
</tr>
<% else %>

<h2>No record found </h2>
<% end %>
<div>
  <%= link_to 'HOME', candidates_path %>
</div>
```

** Message**
[image: error messge]

**from browser**

[image]

And after refreshing the page, it always go to "show" instead of "index".

**Routes created**

[image: rails routes]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: On a side note - use `Candidate.find(params[:id])` and not `find_by`. This will raise an exception if the record is not found which Rails rescues and sends a `404 - Not Found` response. If you use `find_by` you will instead get a bunch of nil errors since you're just continuing no matter if the the record is found or not which will cause a `500 - Internal Server Error`.

Comment: @max Noted. Def changing all `find_by` to `find`. Thanks Max!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `candidates_path` method, not the `'candidates_path'` string:

```rb
  redirect_to candidates_path
```